# Will an older clown fish in a small talk be ok with introducing a new one?

Tags: fish, aquarium, saltwater, clownfish

I have nano tank that is down two one clown and one wrasse. I had two clowns for around 3 years but one just died. The two had paired up and were always right on top of eachother since I got them years ago. I want to introduce another fish to the tank now but wanted to ask if it matters if I add a mature or juvenile clown at this point. Or should I just let the old girl live alone with her crazy wrasse roommate? The smaller one died which I was under the impression that that is the male when they pair up. Anyway, any input is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the size/layout of your tank as well as the species/temperament of each clownfish.  Most likely you won't have much success adding a new one.  I did experiment with different scenarios with mixed success, see my answer in the above question.